# how to create a flask web service when asp.net as the frontend

Tags: python, asp.net, web-services, flask, cmd

I have built a web application using asp.net. and created a web service using command prompt process-`System.Diagnostics.process` usually ill get the values from the user then pass it to the server's cmd prompt, this will run the python script using the given values as python script parameters.

As it is running by cmd-`System.Diagnostics.process`, it takes more time to initialize and run the script.

So I decided to go with Flask framework, I tried with some html files and works fine, but while working with asp.net as front end. It is not working as expected.

My pythonscript:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/success/<name>')
def success(name):
   return "<h1>'welcome %s' </h1>"% name

@app.route('/Login.aspx',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      user = request.form['nm']
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))
   else:
      user = request.args.get('nm')
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))
@app.route("/index/<name>")
def index(name):
   return render_template('hello.html',name=name)

@app.route('/hello/<int:score>')
def hello_name(score):
   return render_template('marks.html', marks = score)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

I also tried changing to the visual studio port in `app.run(debug = True,port=62500)` I am getting `OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbid
den by its access permissions` please help.

**Or suggest me any other way of creating web service to run my python script in server from a asp.net webpage**